# Approximating bounded operators in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space, show that every bounded operator from H to itself  can be approximated in the strong operator topology by a sequence of finite rank operators.

I know we can find an orthonormal basis for the hilbert space. If we let $P_n$ the the projection on the first $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ basis elements, how close can we come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Given $T\in L(H)$, what can you say about $P_nT$?

---

$\def\n#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\def\p#1{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}$
Added: For each $x \in H$ we have $x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i e_i$ for $\alpha_i = \langle x, e_i\rangle$. We get, as the $e_i$ are orthonormal
\begin{align*}
  \n{P_nx - x}^2 &= \n{\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \alpha_i e_i}^2\\
       &= \p{\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \alpha_i e_i, \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty \alpha_j e_j}\\
       &= \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty \alpha_i \bar\alpha_j \p{e_i,e_j}\\
       &= \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty |\alpha_i|^2
\end{align*}
And the latter converges to 0, as $\sum_{i=1}^\infty|\alpha_i|^2 = \n x^2 < \infty$.

Comment: I read that $\|P_nx -x\| \rightarrow 0$ but how is that? I get $\|P_nx -x \| = \|\sum_{i = n+1}^\infty \alpha_ie_i\|$ but does that need to go to 0?

Comment: Added sth. about it.

Comment: Great! So this say that $P_nT \rightarrow T$ pointwise? and we are done?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$